# ExpressionEngine mail form with attachments: how do it?

Tags: attachment

What is the best way to do it a mail form in expressionengine with a file attachment?
The objective is to construct a resumé sender mail form, where the user fill some fields and attach a PDF or DOC file.

I dont want to store this in the site, just attach and send in a e-mail recipient.

What solution to use? Code examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using [Freeform](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/freeform/) from Solspace? There's a paid and free version, both of which should take care of your needs. I use Freeform all the time for a resume upload and email type of form.

EDIT: There are some good code examples in the [Freeform Docs](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/) (at the bottom of the page).

Comment: Another tip: When allowing PDFs to be uploaded, you may need to adjust your EE security preferences to disable XSS filtering for file uploads, otherwise a lot of PDFs get blocked from uploading.

Comment: Nice. I have it Freeform Pro here, but i dont used yet, because the native expressionengine mail forms ever supplied my objectives.

Can you share a code example?

Comment: I've edited the answer to add a link to the FreeForm docs for code examples. Hope that's ok. Cheers.